# не передаются переменные из html в php

Tags: php

передаю две переменные в kat11.php

```
<form action="kat11.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="korsina"& a="3333"  size="3" required>
<input type="submit" value="ввод">
</form>
```

однако вторая переменная a не передается и распечатывается только одна первая

kat11.php

```
$kor=$_GET['korsina'];
echo " програм kat11=".$kor."далее".$a;
print_r($_GET);
```

что не так?
помогите, кто разбирается!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="kat11.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="korsina" size="3" required>
<input type="text" name="a" value="3333" size="3" required>
<input type="submit" value="ввод">
</form>

$kor=$_GET['korsina'];
$a=$_GET['a'];
echo " програм kat11=".$kor."далее".$a;
print_r($_GET);
```